# Shopify - How to display only one tag that contains specific prefix?

Tags: shopify, development-environment

I am looking for solution about to display only one tag which contains a specific prefix instead of displaying all tags. The below  tag display all tags while i want to display only that tag which has a specific prefix.

```
{% assign productTags = product.tags | downcase %}
{% if productTags contains 'prefix_' %}

{{productTags}}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop all tags and check them.

```
{% assign productTags = product.tags | downcase %}
{% for tag in productTags %}
    {% if tag contains 'prefix_' %}
        {{tag}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```